# Store file to Wireless External Storage

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to store my database file from my android application to wireless storage device without using 3rd party app.I need to store the file through my application using WiFi.Help needed

Comment: What exactly is your "wireless storage device"? When you asked the manufacturer of your "wireless storage device" how to work with it from Android, what did the manufacturer tell you?

Comment: I am using Dlink dir505 which is having file sharing functionality through USB port.So i am thinking to insert Flash Drive to USB port and access it from my app instead of using Dlink File share App.

Comment: You will have to see what sort of protocols the device supports. "WiFi" is not a way to share files, any more than "a copper wire" is a way to share files. This D-Link device must have some network protocol that allows other hardware to communicate with the D-Link device for file sharing. That might be a standard protocol (e.g., SMB, used on Windows networks) or it might not.

Comment: So how do they(D-link) design app for file sharing

Comment: You would have to ask D-Link.

Comment: Yes they said I can use SMB protocol but how should I start with this

Comment: Off the cuff, I recommend reviewing [these 161 search results on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+smb). I have not tried using jCIFS or other Java-based SMB clients on Android, though I know that plenty of others have.